Constructing an explicit isomorphism between extension of a finite field and quotient of ring of integers by a prime ideal
Consider the number field $K := \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3 - 3x + 1)$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ satisfies the equation $\alpha^3 - 3\alpha + 1 = 0$. A short calculation shows that $5\mathcal{O}_K = \mathfrak{P}_5$ is prime in $\mathcal{O}_K$, since $$ \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3 - 3x + 1, 5) \cong \mathbb{F_5}[x]/(x^3 - 3x + 1),$$ where $x^3 - 3x + 1$ is irreducible $\bmod{5}$. Then $J := (x^3 - 3x + 1)$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{F_5}[x]$, and $\mathbb{F_5}[x]/(J)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{P}_5\mathcal{O}_K$ as a finite field of order $5^3$.

Question. How do I construct such an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{P}_5\mathcal{O}_K \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathbb{F_{5^3}} = \mathbb{F_5}[x]/(J)$ in SAGE or MAGMA?


MAGMA code:
R<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals());
K := ext<Rationals() | x^3 - 3*x + 1>;
O := Integers(K);
Omodp, Omodpmap:= quo<O | 5*O>;
p := Setseq(Support(5*O))[1];
Kp, Kpmap := Completion(K,p);
Op := Integers(Kp);
Fq, Fqmap := ResidueClassField(Op);
FqtoOmodp := Inverse(Fqmap)*Inverse(Kpmap)*Omodpmap;

This sets up a map as composition of the maps in the following diagram from left to right:
$$\mathbb{F_q} \xleftarrow{\text{Fqmap}} K_\mathfrak{p} \xleftarrow{\text{Kpmap}} K \xrightarrow{\text{Omodpmap}} \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O} $$
and we check that the image is of the right size:
> #{i @ FqtoOmodp : i in Fq};
125


Why are you passing to the completion? I don't think that is necessary. Doesn't R<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals()); K<nu> := NumberField(x^3 - 3*x + 1); OK := Integers(K); I := 5*OK; Fq, phi := ResidueClassField(I); accomplish the same thing?

Well, I didn't know you could call that from ideals straight away. Could've saved a lot of time on my own code from this.

Thank you, Viktor and Victor!
